# mongodb aggregate query isn't returning proper sum on using $sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection students with documents in the following format:-

```
{
 _id:"53fe74a866455060e003c2db",
 name:"sam",
 subject:"maths",
 marks:"77"
}
{
 _id:"53fe79cbef038fee879263d2",
 name:"ryan", 
 subject:"bio",
 marks:"82"
}
{
 _id:"53fe74a866456060e003c2de",
 name:"tony",
 subject:"maths",
 marks:"86"
}
```

I want to get the count of total marks of all the students with subject = "maths". So I should get 163 as sum.

```
db.students.aggregate([{ $match : { subject : "maths" } },
{ "$group" : { _id : "$subject", totalMarks : { $sum : "$marks" } } }])
```

Now I should get the following result-

```
{"result":[{"_id":"53fe74a866455060e003c2db", "totalMarks":163}], "ok":1}
```

But I get-

```
{"result":[{"_id":"53fe74a866455060e003c2db", "totalMarks":0}], "ok":1}
```

Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: problem in `marks` fields actually `marks` stored in `string` data type so `mongo sum` on string not work, you should change `mark` data type

Comment: Oh yes! You are right. I couldn't spot this. Thank you! Why don't you write this as an answer. I will be able to mark is as correct that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current schema has the `marks` field data type as string and you need an integer data type for your aggregation framework to work out the sum. On the other hand, you can use [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) to calculate the sum since it allows the use of native JavaScript methods like `parseInt()` on your object properties in its map functions. So overall you have two choices.

---

### **Option 1: Update Schema (Change Data Type)**

The first would be to change the schema or add another field in your document that has the actual numerical value not the string representation. If your collection document size is relatively small, you could use a combination of the mongodb's cursor **`find()`**, **`forEach()`** and **`update()`** methods to change your marks schema:

```
db.student.find({ "marks": { "$type": 2 } }).snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
    db.student.update(
        { "_id": doc._id, "marks": { "$type": 2 } }, 
        { "$set": { "marks": parseInt(doc.marks) } }
    );
});
```

For relatively large collection sizes, your db performance will be slow and it's recommended to use [mongo bulk updates](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) for this:

**MongoDB versions >= 2.6 and < 3.2:**

```
var bulk = db.student.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.student.find({"marks": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function (doc) {    
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "marks": parseInt(doc.marks) } 
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations 
        bulk.execute(); 

        // re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk = db.student.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up remaining operations in queue
if (counter % 1000 !== 0) bulk.execute();
```

**MongoDB version 3.2 and newer:**

```
var ops = [],
    cursor = db.student.find({"marks": {"$exists": true, "$type": 2 }});

cursor.forEach(function (doc) {     
    ops.push({ 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id } ,              
            "update": { "$set": { "marks": parseInt(doc.marks) } } 
        }         
    });

    if (ops.length === 1000) {
        db.student.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }     
});

if (ops.length > 0) db.student.bulkWrite(ops);
```

---

### **Option 2: Run MapReduce**

The second approach would be to rewrite your query with [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) where you can use the JavaScript function `parseInt()`.

In your [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) operation, define the map function that process each input document. This function maps the converted `marks` string value to the `subject` for each document, and emits the `subject` and converted `marks` pair. This is where the JavaScript native function `parseInt()` can be applied. Note: in the function, `this` refers to the document that the map-reduce operation is processing:

```
var mapper = function () {
    var x = parseInt(this.marks);
    emit(this.subject, x);
};
```

Next, define the corresponding reduce function with two arguments `keySubject` and `valuesMarks`. `valuesMarks` is an array whose elements are the integer `marks` values emitted by the map function and grouped by `keySubject`.
The function reduces the `valuesMarks` array to the sum of its elements.

```
var reducer = function(keySubject, valuesMarks) {
    return Array.sum(valuesMarks);
};

db.student.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
    {
        out : "example_results",
        query: { subject : "maths" }       
    }
 );
```

With your collection, the above will put your MapReduce aggregation result in a new collection `db.example_results`. Thus, `db.example_results.find()` will output:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "maths",
    "value" : 163
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes your sum is being returned 0 are :

1. The field you are summing up is not an integer but a string.

   **Make sure the field contains numeric values.**
2. You are using wrong syntax of $sum.

   `db.c1.aggregate([{
       $group: {
           _id: "$item",
           price: {
               $sum: "$price"
           },
           count: {
               $sum: 1
           }
       }
   }])`

   Make sure you use "$price" and not "price".
3. One of the most silly mistake due to which this error occurs is:

   Use of space or tab inside the quotes while specifying field name.

   Example - **"$price " won't work !!!** But, **"$price" would work.**